# Remove Body Classes

Tags: custom-field, array, body-class

I need to remove specific body classes added as a comma separated delimited list to a custom field input field like this

```
wp-custom-logo, single-post, postid-28, single-format-standard, logged-in, admin-bar
```

Using this code only allows me to remove 1 class

```
add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {

if ( ! is_singular(array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
    return;
}

$body_classes = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_remove_body_classes', true );

unset( $classes[array_search($body_classes, $classes)] );

return $classes;

});
```

This code works when trying to remove 1 class on single posts but doesn't work when using a comma delimited list and also doesn't work on single pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (untested) suggestion is to replace:

```
unset( $classes[array_search($body_classes, $classes)] );
```

with

```
$classes = array_diff( $classes, wp_parse_slug_list( $body_classes ) );
```

assuming the classes survive `sanitize_title` from [`wp_parse_slug_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_slug_list/). It should also be alright with empty arrays.

We also note that `wp_parse_slug_list()` is using [`wp_parse_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_list/) to parse the comma separated string.

Comment: Awesome stuff, been banging my head against the wall for hours trying to fix this. You're a rockstar @birgire

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked for you @Michelle